# Why is my "count" variable not incrementing everytime I create a new instance of the Student class?

Tags: python, oop

Why is my "count" variable not incrementing everytime I create a new instance of the Student class?

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,sNam,sADD):
        global count  

        count = 1

        self.studentName = sNam
        self.studentAddress = sADD
        self.studentID = count

        count = count + 1


        print"Student",self.studentID ,"name is:",self.studentName
        print "Student",self.studentID ,"address is:",self.studentAddress
```

Comment: Because you're re-initializing it every time.

Comment: You are setting count to 1

Answer (score 4):

Because of this line:

```
count = 1
```

Every time you're creating a new instance of the Student class, you're resetting count back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please format your code.

As of now probably you get '2' all the time?

Every time you create an instace you set `count = 1`, then you set some fields and increment `count = count+1`.

So move `count = 1` above your class declaration and try again.

Comment: What do you mean by "Please format your code"? :) Thanks.

Comment: Before **Ashwini Chaudhary** edited your question, the code in it was not easily readable. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
count = 0

class Student():

def __init__(self,sNam,sADD):
    global count

    count +=1

    self.studentName = sNam
    self.studentAddress = sADD
    self.studentID = count




    print"Student",self.studentID ,"name is:",self.studentName
    print "Student",self.studentID ,"address is:",self.studentAddress


a = Student('John','Diggle')

b = Student('Mia','Kunis')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got stuck in the mindset of including all code in the class itself rather than outside as I was always creating objects using Student().